# What does it mean if the arclength is equal to zero?

Tags: calculus

The problem was to describe the graph of the given set $$C = \{(x,y):x = \sqrt {t-1}, y =\sqrt{1-t}\}$$

Comment: Note that there is only one value of $t$ for which both coordinates are real.

Comment: We have $C=\{(0,0) \}.$